# rngesturehandlermodule.attach gesture handler got 2 arguments expected 3

Tags: react-native

When using the following code this error occurs:

> rngesturehandlermodule.attach gesture handler got 2 arguments expected 3

Code:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
    
    export default class App extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image 
            style={{width:'100%', height:400}}
            source={require('./assets/Login.png')}
            resizeMode='cover' />
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Hello User!</Text>
            <Text style={{color:'gray', marginHorizontal:20, fontSize:10,textAlign:'center'}}> Welcome To The My Application I Am A Naqeeb Rajput The Developer Of The React Native</Text>
          
          
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', paddingVertical:20, margin:20}}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
    
            style={{
              width:100,
              backgroundColor:'#0d47a1', 
              padding:10,
              borderRadius:30,
              marginVertical:1
            
            }}>
                <Text style={{color:'white', textAlign:'center'}}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    
    
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                width:100,
              backgroundColor:'#e3f2fd', 
              padding:10,
              borderRadius:30,
              marginVertical:1
            
            }}>
                <Text style={{color:'black', textAlign:'center'}}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, marginTop:7}}>Or via Social</Text>


            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    


              <View 



style={{justifyContent:'center', width:40, height:40, borderRadius:40/2, backgroundColor:'#283593', alignItems:'center'}}>


              <Text


 style={{color:'white', alignItems:'center', fontSize:15  , fontWeight:'bold'}}>f</Text>
              </View>

              <View 
style={{justifyContent:'center', width:40, height:40, borderRadius:40/2, backgroundColor:'#b71c1c', alignItems:'center'}}>

              <Text
 style={{color:'white', alignItems:'center', fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>g</Text>
              </View>

              <View 
style={{justifyContent:'center', width:40, height:40, borderRadius:40/2, backgroundColor:'#311b92', alignItems:'center'}}>

              <Text
     style={{color:'white', alignItems:'center', fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>In</Text>
              </View>
    
            </View>
    
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: i think its duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257047/rngesturehandlermodule-attach-gesture-handler-got-3-arguments-expected-2

Comment: Yes its similer but my error is still occur

Comment: Please give the full stack trace.